# How can i insert array in session and then constantly push data in that array in the session in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a array in a session so that a guest user in my e-commerce website can have its own wishlist and I can gradually push data selected by the guest.
below is the code I have written for that :-

```
if(Session::has('guest.id')) {
      Session::push('guest.tname', $tname);
      Session::push('guest.pid', $pid);
    }
    else {
        Session::set('guest.id',$guest_id);
        Session::set('guest.tname', $tname);
        Session::set('guest.pid', $pid);

    }
```

But the above code is consistently giving me this error :-

FatalThrowableError in Store.php line 411: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: This line 411 which section of code interest?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as:

```
if(Session::has('guest.id')) {
  Session::push('guest.tname', $tname);
  Session::push('guest.pid', $pid);
}
else {
    Session::set('guest.id',$guest_id);
    Session::push('guest.tname', $tname);
    Session::push('guest.pid', $pid);
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#using-the-session)

Comment: Thanks for replying but still getting the same error.                      FatalThrowableError in Store.php line 411: [] operator not supported for strings